# Could not install custom app in frappe docker bench

Tags: docker, frappe

I am new to frappe docker,I have created a site in frappe docker and its working fine. I created a custom app called test and tried installing it in my site using

./dbench --site site1.local install-app test

But its giving error as could not find app “test”
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAbNm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its working after removing and reinstalling the app.